# React Native Styling

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to understand more about Styling in React Native.

While Dragging a element into bottom container (Yellow), the element goes underneath.

[image]

[image]

```
//View

  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
      <DraggingItem />
    </View>
    <View style={styles.dropContainer}>
           //2nd container
    </View>
  </View>


//STYLING

  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },

  itemContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    height: (window.height*56)/100,
  },

  dropContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    height: (window.height*40)/100,
  },
```

// ITEM STYLE

```
 text: {
    marginTop: 25,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    // alignItems: 'center',
    // justifyContent: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: "#fff"
  },

  item: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    width: window.width,
    height: 80,
    borderRadius: 15
  }
```

Comment: what is DraggingItem  element?

Comment: @maziyank You cant see attached images ?

Comment: is that your own custom component?

Comment: Yes, I added item styles too

Comment: how if you try to move <DraggingItem /> outside the view?

Comment: if i do it, it goes behind a green and yellow. Not on top of it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179216/discussion-between-7urkm3n-and-maziyank).

Comment: Can you post the code to the draggable item

Answer (score 1):

you can try zIndex and read more about it [hear](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp). if zIndex if your yellow box is bigger that red one, the thing happen like you have in your image. if you don't want it, give red one the bigger zIndex.